# How to pass IN parameter to a mysql stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hello Im really new to Java and mysql. I want to know how to pass an IN parameter to my mysql stored procedure by using a callable statement in JAVA. Here is my code below I cant get it to work!

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/"+database, user, pass);

conn.setAutoCommit(false);


CallableStatement cs1 = conn.prepareCall("Call get_school_address_details()");
cs1.setInt(1);

ResultSet res = cs1.executeQuery();

System.out.println("Result of SP");

while (res.next())
{
    System.out.println (res.getString(1) + " " + res.getString(2) + " " + res.getString(3));

}
```

It doesnt seem to like the way i have tried to passs the parameter using cs1.setInt(1)

Suggestions please! All i want to pass it is the value 1 which is an int

Comment: You need to explicitly have the parameter in the procedure call. (eg `{call mysp(?)}`

Comment: I see that but it wont let me add the value 1 to cs1.setInt(1); though

Comment: `setInt` takes two arguments: position and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by passing the parameter name and then the value I wanted to pass which in this case was the number one:

```
cs1.setInt("sch_code",1);
```